# Continuity of $f(x)=m^*(E \cap B(x,r))$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

> Let $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$.
>
> Prove that $f_r(x)=m^*(E \cap B(x,r))$ is continuous $\forall r>0$.
>
> where $m^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure.

My idea is  to prove that $f_r$ is locally Lipschitz.

I could use also  the fact that :

If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable then $$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \setminus E) ,\forall A \subseteq \Bbb{R^n}$$

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find that for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $F\subset \Bbb R^n$
$$
m^*F = m^*(F\cap B(x,r))+m^*(F\setminus B(x,r))
$$ since $B(x,r)$ is measurable. Let $F=E\cap B(y,r)$ to obtain
$$
f(y) =m^*(E\cap B(y,r)\cap B(x,r))+m^*\left(\left(E\cap B(y,r)\right)\setminus B(x,r)\right).
$$ By interchanging $x$ and $y$, we also obtain
$$
f(x) =m^*(E\cap B(x,r)\cap B(y,r))+m^*\left(\left(E\cap B(x,r)\right)\setminus B(y,r)\right).
$$ This yields
$$
f(x)-f(y) =m^*\left(\left(E\cap B(x,r)\right)\setminus B(y,r)\right)-m^*\left(\left(E\cap B(y,r)\right)\setminus B(x,r)\right),
$$ hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)-f(y)&\le& m^*\left(\left(E\cap B(x,r)\right)\setminus B(y,r)\right)\\
&\le&m^*\left( B(x,r)\setminus B(y,r)\right)\\
&\le& m^*\left( B(x,r+|x-y|)\setminus B(y,r)\right)\\
&=&m^*B(x,r+|x-y|)-m^*B(y,r)\\&=&\omega_n \left[(r+|x-y|)^n-r^n\right]
\end{eqnarray}$$ where $\omega_n=m^*B(0,1)$ is the volume of the unit ball. By interchanging $x$ and $y$ we also find that
$$
f(x)-f(y)\ge -\omega_n \left[(r+|x-y|)^n-r^n\right].
$$Therefore 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le \omega_n \left[(r+|x-y|)^n-r^n\right] \stackrel{|x-y|\to 0}\longrightarrow 0,
$$ which proves (uniform) continuity of $f$ as desired.

Note: Since
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le \omega_n |x-y|\left[(r+|x-y|)^{n-1} +(r+|x-y|)^{n-2}r +\cdots +r^{n-1}\right],
$$ your conjecture that $f$ is locally Lipschitz is correct.